# Why use YUI filter in web.xml css or js file not load

Tags: spring-mvc, yui, minify

I want to use YUI to minify and compressed css and js files in spring mvc. so use this filter and add it to web.xml but when run project all css and js files not loaded. what is my problem?

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>yuiMinFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.YUIMinFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
            <param-name>lineBreak</param-name>
            <param-value>8000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>yuiMinFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Facing same problem.Any alternative to this filter